# My sprite will not display, I am making a side scroller on as3

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, movieclip

I am making a game where my rocket ship has to avoid asteroids. However, my rocket ship sprite will not display. Any helps is appreciated.

```
          var myRocket:MovieClip;
          addChild(myRocket);
          myRocket.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
          myRocket.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
          myRocket.x=200;
          myRocket.y=150;
```

Comment: You declared the variable for your rocket ship, but never created/instantiated it.

Comment: @Organis I have a sprite named myRocket in my library, yet when I start the game it is not there :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that's how you instantiate things from Library.

First, the Library object must have an AS3 class. You assign it in the Library object's properties. Let's say the class name is **SpaceRocket**.

Then you do the following:

```
// Instantiate the object by its class.
var rocket:SpaceRocket = new SpaceRocket;

// Assign coordinates.
rocket.x = 200;
rocket.y = 150;

// Add the instance to the display list.
addChild(rocket);
```

Also, I don't recommend listening the **rocket** for the keyboard events. It means the **rocket** should have the keyboard focus, which can be lost quite easily. You should rather listen it at the **stage** because all the keyboard events go there eventually:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
```